# Pandas Dataframe Create Seaborn Horizontal Barplot with categorical data

Tags: pandas, group-by, bar-chart, seaborn, categorical-data

I'm currently working with a data frame like this:

[image]

What I want is to show the total numer of the **Victory** column where the value is S grouped by **AGE_GROUP** and differenced by **GENDER**, something like in the following horizontal barplot:

[image]

Until now I could obtain the following chart:

[image]

Following this steps:

```
victory_df = main_df[main_df["VICTORY"] == "S"]
victory_count = victory_df["AGE_GROUP"].value_counts()
sns.set(style="darkgrid")
sns.barplot(victory_count.index, victory_count.values, alpha=0.9)
```

Which strategy I should use to difference in the value_count by gender and include it in the chart?

Comment: Is there a reason why you wanted a stacked horizontal bar in seaborn and not matplot lib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would obviously help giving raw data and not an image. Came up with own data.Not sure understood your question but my attempt below.

Data

```
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'VICTORY':['S', 'S', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'S', 'N', 'S', 'N', 'S', 'N', 'S', 'S'],'AGE':[5., 88., 12., 19., 30., 43., 77., 50., 78., 34., 45.,  9., 67.],'AGE_GROUP':['0-13', '65+', '0-13', '18-35', '18-35', '36-64', '65+', '36-64','65+', '18-35', '36-64', '0-13', '65+'],'GENDER':['M', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'F']})
```

Plotting. I groupby AGE_GROUP, [value count](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) GENDER, [unstack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and plot a [stacked](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_stacked.html) horizontal bar plot. Seaborn is build on matplotlib and when plotting is not straightforward in seaborn like the stacked horizontal bar, I fall back to matplotlib. Hope you dont take offence.

```
   df[df['VICTORY']=='S'].groupby('AGE_GROUP')['GENDER'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts()).unstack().plot(kind='barh', stacked=True)

plt.xlabel('Count')
plt.title('xxxx')
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Sorry for not adding raw data, that will work fine for me.